# Bridge IP address across different range

Tags: networking, router

Ive got a piece of hardware (Lutron lighting system) that has a static IP of `192.168.1.201`. I dont have the Lutron lighting software to hand so cant login and change the static IP or set it to use DHCP.

I the network range for the rest of the building is `192.168.22.xxx`.

Is there a way in the router i could bridge `192.168.1.201` to `192.168.22.201` so that other devices on `192.168.22.xxx` can speak to it ?

The router im using is a Draytek 2860.

Comment: Multiple IP networks can run over the same Ethernet segment. You should be able to simply add an additional IP address within the desired range to an existing machine on the same LAN.

Comment: You may simply be able to change the netmask to 255.255.0.0.

Comment: You might check the official model documentation for a feature called Static Routing that may help with this sort of task if changing the netmask is not an option for the machines you need to talk with the other subnet. https://www.draytek.co.uk/support/downloads/vigor-2860/older-firmware/firmware-3844/send/456-3844/706-vigor2860-user-guide-v4-2 .... Easy enough to try I would think at least.